# Number of controllers for multipage survey questionnaire Laravel / PHP

Tags: php, laravel

I am building a survey questionnaire in PHP using Laravel and there are five HTML pages (one for each section). Do I need to create separate controllers for each HTML page in order to process the data to the database?

Answer (score 0):

Usually it is good to stick to the different logic-different controller.
As you provided very small amount of info, its not clear what you want to do, but based on the info I understand, you’ll just need one controller and one method for all the html pages.